# Create objects instead of articles in joomla?

Tags: php, html, object, joomla, joomla-extensions

Im trying to make a web in joomla kind of:
http://www.cuevana.tv/#!/peliculas 
It will not be about, films nor online streaming, but im thinking in have "objects".
I have checked that site and i notice that the films are kind of objects, they have:
Genre, Language, Actors, Title, Category etc etc.
In joomla i have the option to make only articles, but with articles i can't have attributes.
Any idea on how can i achieve this ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you need is a 3rd party component to extend Joomla and provide CCK capabilities.
Look for Zoo, K2, SobiPro, Fabrik.

Comment: Thanks, now im using k2, and with the "Extra fields" option i think im doing it right. It's not the best solution, but may work.

Comment: You got it.  Each of these Cotnetn Creation Kits have different strengths and weaknesses.  Mine favourite for simple stuff is Zoo but I expand that even further with more 3rd party stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean exactly but with Joomla 3.1 you can assign tags. I'm not sure though what you mean by saying that articles don't have titles... articles and all content items in the core have titles, images, links, keywords, teaser text, and in 3.1 tags.

I'm assuming you want to be able to search based on these attributes so really I think nested tags are going to help you and you may want to use plugins to extend the tags api.  Also Smart Search maps will possibly be helpful.